# Apache Cordova iOS Api issue

Tags: ios, angular, rest, cordova

I am working on a Cordova application with Angular for the UI and generating Android and iOS builds. Inside my application, I am calling a REST API, and it is working fine on Android. However, on iOS, it is not working. When I debug the iOS application, I found that the **origin** in the API request on iOS is going with `app://******.****.com`, whereas in Android, it is going to `https://******.***.com`, and it is working perfectly.

Please find my `config.xml` file for Cordova below:

```
<content src="index.html" />

<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />

<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="scheme" value="https"/>
    <preference name="hostname" value="*****.*****.com" />
</platform>

<platform name="android">
    <preference name="scheme" value="https"/>
    <preference name="hostname" value="*****.*******.com" />
</platform>

<platform name="browser">
    <!-- Other browser platform configuration options -->
    <browserify port="9867" />
</platform>
```

My question is, why is the scheme value (`https`) not set in iOS? It is always going with the `app` prefix. How can I replace `app` with `https`? Please provide any suggestions on this. Thanks in advance.

I tried using `cordova-plugin-whitelist`, but it didn't change anything. I'm still facing the same problem.